# Integral of Motion in the 1D Calogero Model

Tags: classical-mechanics, integrals-of-motion

In section 4 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03843), suppose we have $N$ particles of the same mass $m$ moving in one dimension and interacting with each other via the potential $V_{ij}\equiv V(x_i - x_j)$, where $x_i$ denotes the position of the $i$-th particle. Because the total momentum
$$
I_1 = m\sum_i \dot{x}_i
$$
and energy
$$
E = \frac{m}{2}\sum_i \dot{x}_i^2 + \sum_{1\leqslant i < j\leqslant N}V_{ij}
$$
are conserved, we have that
$$
I_2:= \frac{1}{2}I_1^2 - E = \left(m^2\sum_{1\leqslant i < j\leqslant N}\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j\right) - \left(\sum_{1\leqslant i < j\leqslant N}V_{ij}\right).
$$
is also conserved.

I am stuck when trying to derive $I_3$ in the article, with the same constraints (that is, $\sum_{1\leqslant i < j < k\leqslant N}V_{ij}'V_{jk} = 0$). I do not have any clue for deriving the expression of $I_3$ (which is also a constant) as proposed in the article:

$$
I_3 = \left(m^3\sum_{1\leqslant i<j<k\leqslant N}\dot{x_i}\dot{x_j}\dot{x_k}\right) - \left(m\sum_{1\leqslant i<j<k\leqslant N}\dot{x}_i V_{jk}\right).
$$

Could anyone please provide some hints? Any of your help will be greatly appreciated! :)

---

**Please Note:**  I am also a little bewildered about the derivation of $I_2$. I am not sure whether it is a typo in the document, but it seems that

$$
I_2 = \frac{1}{2m}I_1^2 - E = \left(m\sum_{1\leqslant i < j\leqslant N} \dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j\right) - \left(\sum_{1\leqslant i < j\leqslant N}V_{ij}\right)
$$

makes more sense than that in the article, in which I am not sure how the terms $\frac{m^2}{2} \sum_i \dot{x}_i^2$ and $\frac{m}{2}\sum_i \dot{x}_i^2$ cancelled out.

Answer (score 0):

for 2 particles

$$T=\frac m2\,(\dot{x}_1^2+\dot{x}_2^2)$$
$$V=\frac 12 \,(x_1^2+(x_2-x_1)^2)=-x_2\,x_1$$
$$E=T+V$$
$$p=m\,(\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2)$$

thus :

$$I_2=\frac 12\,p^2-E=m^2\,\dot{x}_1\,\dot{x}_2-V(x_1\,x_2)$$

with : $$\dot{x}_1^2=0~,\dot{x}_2^2=0~,x_1^2=0~,x_2^2=0$$

for 3 particles

$$T=\frac m2\,(\dot{x}_1^2+\dot{x}_2^2+\dot{x}_2^3)$$
$$V=\frac 12\,(x_1^2+(x_2-x_1)^2+(x_3-x_2)^2))=-x_1\,x_2-x_2\,x_3$$
$$E=T+V$$
$$p=m\,(\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2+\dot{x}_3)$$
thus:

$$I_3=\frac 12\,p^3-p\,E=3\,m^3\,\dot{x}_1\,\dot{x}_2\,\dot{x}_3-p\,V$$

**Edit**

all square  and cubic products are zero

$$\frac 12\,p^3=\frac 12\,m^3\,(\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2+\dot{x}_3)^3:=3\,m^3\dot{x}_1\dot{x}_2\dot{x}_3$$

$$-p\,E=-p\,(T+V)=-p\,(\frac m2\,(\dot{x}_1^2+\dot{x}_2^2+\dot{x}_2^3))-p\,V:=-p\,0-p\,V$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I have tried several times to evaluate $I_3$, and I just could not get the same result as shown in your answer. Could you please show how you derived it more explicitly?

Comment: @ArGenya I wrote you more information